# (*p)->left->prev means *p

Tags: c, pointers, data-structures, red-black-tree

I wrote a red-black tree program implementation.
I ran into a problem in the `left_rotation` function.

```c
void left_rotation(node **p)
{
    node *left_son = LEFT_SON_VAR_PAR; /* (*p)->left */
    node *dad = DAD_VAR_PAR;
    node *grandpa = GRANDPA_VAR_PAR;
    grandpa->left = *p;
    (*p)->prev = grandpa;
    dad->prev = *p;
    dad->right = left_son;
    if (left_son)
        left_son->prev = dad;
    (*p)->left = dad;
}
```

It turned out that the `left_son->prev = dad;` part equivalent to `*p = (*p)->prev;`.

Here is the programs minimal reproducible example:

```c
/* red-black_tree.c */

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

#define GREATGRANDPA_VAR_PAR (*p)->prev->prev->prev
#define GRANDPA_VAR_PAR (*p)->prev->prev
#define RIGHT_UNCLE_VAR_PAR (*p)->prev->prev->right
#define LEFT_UNCLE_VAR_PAR (*p)->prev->prev->left
#define RIGHT_UNCLE p->prev->prev->right
#define LEFT_UNCLE p->prev->prev->left
#define DAD_VAR_PAR (*p)->prev
#define DAD p->prev
#define RIGHT_BRO_VAR_PAR (*p)->prev->right
#define LEFT_BRO_VAR_PAR (*p)->prev->left
#define RIGHT_BRO p->prev->right
#define LEFT_BRO p->prev->left
#define LEFT_SON_VAR_PAR (*p)->left

typedef enum tag_node_color { red, black } node_color;

typedef struct tag_node {
    struct tag_node *left, *right, *prev;
    int value;
    node_color color;
} node;

void find_node(int num, node **p, node **previous, node ***position)
{
    if ((!*p) || ((*p)->value == num)) {
        *position = p;
        return;
    }
    *previous = *p;
    if (num < (*p)->value)
        find_node(num, &(*p)->left, previous, position);
    else
        find_node(num, &(*p)->right, previous, position);
}

int tree_height(node *p)
{
    int curr_height = 0;
    if (!p)
        return 0;
    if (tree_height(p->left) >= tree_height(p->right))
        curr_height = tree_height(p->left);
    else
        curr_height = tree_height(p->right);
    return curr_height + 1;
}

node **current_root_is(node **p)
{
    return (!DAD_VAR_PAR) ? p : current_root_is(&DAD_VAR_PAR);
}

bool grandpa_is_right_son(node *p)
{
    return (p->value == RIGHT_BRO->value) ? true : false;
}

void left_rotation_and_recolor(node **p)
{
    node *dad = DAD_VAR_PAR;
    node *left_bro = LEFT_BRO_VAR_PAR;
    node *grandpa = GRANDPA_VAR_PAR;
    node *great_grandpa = GREATGRANDPA_VAR_PAR;
    if (great_grandpa) {
        if (grandpa_is_right_son(grandpa))
            great_grandpa->right = dad;
        else
            great_grandpa->left = dad;
    }
    if (left_bro)
        left_bro->prev = grandpa;
    grandpa->right = left_bro;
    dad->left = grandpa;
    dad->prev = great_grandpa;
    grandpa->prev = dad;
    dad->color = black;
    grandpa->color = red;
}

void right_rotation_and_recolor(node **p)
{
    node *dad = DAD_VAR_PAR;
    node *right_bro = RIGHT_BRO_VAR_PAR;
    node *grandpa = GRANDPA_VAR_PAR;
    node *great_grandpa = GREATGRANDPA_VAR_PAR;
    if (great_grandpa) {
        if (grandpa_is_right_son(grandpa))
            great_grandpa->right = dad;
        else
            great_grandpa->left = dad;
    }
    if (right_bro)
        right_bro->prev = grandpa;
    grandpa->left = right_bro;
    dad->right = grandpa;
    dad->prev = great_grandpa;
    grandpa->prev = dad;
    dad->color = black;
    grandpa->color = red;
}

bool dad_is_left_son(node *p)
{
    if (!LEFT_UNCLE)
        return false;
    if (LEFT_UNCLE->value == DAD->value)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}

bool dad_is_right_son(node *p)
{
    if (!RIGHT_UNCLE)
        return false;
    if (RIGHT_UNCLE->value == DAD->value)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}

bool im_left_son(node *p)
{
    if (!LEFT_BRO)
        return false;
    if (LEFT_BRO->value == p->value)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}

bool im_right_son(node *p)
{
    if (!RIGHT_BRO)
        return false;
    if (RIGHT_BRO->value == p->value)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}

bool uncle_is_black(node *p)                        /* technically I check */
{                                       /* if both parent and uncle are black */
    if ((!LEFT_UNCLE) || (!RIGHT_UNCLE))
        return true;
    if ((LEFT_UNCLE->color == black) || (RIGHT_UNCLE->color == black))
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}

void set_grandpa_color_red(node **p)
{
    if (!GREATGRANDPA_VAR_PAR)
        return;
    else
        GRANDPA_VAR_PAR->color = red;
}

void set_dad_and_uncle_colors_black(node **p)
{
    if ((!LEFT_UNCLE_VAR_PAR) || (!RIGHT_UNCLE_VAR_PAR))
        return;
    LEFT_UNCLE_VAR_PAR->color = black;
    RIGHT_UNCLE_VAR_PAR->color = black;
}

void self_balance(node **p);

void recolor(node **p)
{
    set_dad_and_uncle_colors_black(p);
    set_grandpa_color_red(p);
    self_balance(&GRANDPA_VAR_PAR);
}

bool uncle_is_red(node *p)                          /* technically I check */
{                                       /* if both parent and uncle are red */
    if ((!LEFT_UNCLE) || (!RIGHT_UNCLE))
        return false;
    if ((LEFT_UNCLE->color == red) &&
        (RIGHT_UNCLE->color == red))
    {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

bool dad_is_red(node *p)
{
    return (DAD->color == red) ? true : false;
}

bool dad_is_black(node *p)
{
    return (DAD->color == black) ? true : false;
}

void left_rotation(node **p)
{
    node *left_son = LEFT_SON_VAR_PAR; /* (*p)->left */
    node *dad = DAD_VAR_PAR;
    node *grandpa = GRANDPA_VAR_PAR;
    grandpa->left = *p;
    (*p)->prev = grandpa;
    dad->prev = *p;
    dad->right = left_son;
    if (left_son)
        left_son->prev = dad;
    (*p)->left = dad;
}

void self_balance(node **p)
{
    if ((!DAD_VAR_PAR) || (dad_is_black(*p)) || ((*p)->color == black))
        return;
    if (dad_is_red(*p)) {
        if (uncle_is_red(*p)) {
            recolor(p);
            self_balance(&GRANDPA_VAR_PAR);
        } else
        if (uncle_is_black(*p) && im_right_son(*p) && dad_is_right_son(*p)) {
            left_rotation_and_recolor(p);
            self_balance(&DAD_VAR_PAR);
        } else
        if (uncle_is_black(*p) && im_left_son(*p) && dad_is_left_son(*p)) {
            right_rotation_and_recolor(p);
            self_balance(&DAD_VAR_PAR);
        } else
        if (uncle_is_black(*p) && im_right_son(*p) && dad_is_left_son(*p)) {
            left_rotation(p);
            right_rotation_and_recolor(&(*p)->left);
            self_balance(p);
        }
    }
}

void add_node(node **p, int num, int *height)
{
    node *previous = NULL;
    node **position = NULL;
    find_node(num, p, &previous, &position);
    if (*position != NULL)
        printf("The node %d already exists.\n", num);
    else {
        *position = malloc(sizeof(node));
        (*position)->value = num;
        (*position)->right = NULL;
        (*position)->left = NULL;
        (*position)->prev = previous;
        if ((*position)->prev) {
            (*position)->color = red;
            self_balance(position);
            position = current_root_is(position);   /* check if the root was */
            *p = *position;                     /* changed and set a new root */
        } else 
            (*position)->color = black;         /* it's the very 1st node */
        *height = tree_height(*p);
    }
}

void print_color_and_dad_value(node *p)
{
    if (p->color == black)
        printf(",blk(");
    else
        printf(",red(");
    if (p->prev == NULL)
        printf(" ) ");
    else
        printf("%d) ", p->prev->value);
}

void print_tree_level(node *p, int height, int curr_height)
{
    if (!p)
        return;
    if (height == curr_height) {
        printf("%d", p->value);
        print_color_and_dad_value(p);
    } else {
        print_tree_level(p->left, height, curr_height+1);
        print_tree_level(p->right, height, curr_height+1);
    }
}

void print_tree(node *p, int height)
{
    int i;
    for (i=1; i <= height; i++) {
        print_tree_level(p, i, 1);
        putchar('\n');
    }
}

void free_tree(node *p)
{
    if (!p)
        return;
    free_tree(p->left);
    free_tree(p->right);
    free(p);
}

int main()
{
    node *root = NULL;
    int i, height = 0;
    int num[] = { 50, 20, 60, 70, 10, 30, 25, 40, 22 };
    for (i=0; i < (int)(sizeof(num)/sizeof(num[0])); i++)
        add_node(&root, num[i], &height);
    putchar('\n');
    print_tree(root, height);
    printf("Current tree height is %d.\n", height);
    free_tree(root);
    return 0;
}
```

I see that in the line 228 `self_balance(&GRANDPA_VAR_PAR);` I myself passed to the function the very address which I can't edit later in the `left_rotation` function.

I know that one way to fix the problem is to change the `left_rotation` function argument from `node **` to `node *`. But I wonder if there is a way to fix the function in it's current state.

I tried to rewrite the part starting with the line 226

```c
        if (uncle_is_red(*p)) {
            recolor(p);
            self_balance(&GRANDPA_VAR_PAR);
        } else
```

as

```c
        if (uncle_is_red(*p)) {
            node *tmp = GRANDPA_VAR_PAR;
            recolor(p);
            self_balance(&tmp);
        } else
```

but it didn't help.

I would appreciate any advice :)

Comment: Please don't use such macros. They don't help making the code better in any way, quite the opposite. The code is much harder to read and understand and maintain.

Comment: I'm sorry but I doubt that that is a _minimal_ reproducible example. That looks to me like all your source code.

Comment: There's also a lot of extra indirection that doesn't seem to be needed. The less pointers you have, the less indirections, the less chances for errors. Especially since you don't have enough null-pointer checks. And being a [three-star programmer](https://wiki.c2.com/?ThreeStarProgrammer) is not a good thing.

Comment: Why have you [deleted](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77540772/5459839) this same question only to repost it again? Now the comments to that original question are not available here. Not really helpful.

Comment: I believe it will be faster to start from scratch than to debug this. After reading `***position` I stopped. And when you do start from scratch, please unit test each function you write before continuing with more code.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude 
Hmm, do you think it's better for me to use constructs like `(*p)->prev->prev->prev` and `(*p)->prev->prev->right` in my code not trying to hide them in any way?

Comment: @BRemmelzwaal
I did cut out the input part though :)
If I continued to cut the programs functions it would not be a red-black tree anymore.
In the first version of my question I didn't even provide the the program text. I think the problem is localized inside the `left_rotation` function and the program text serves rather as a context.

Comment: @trincot
I deleted the original question because I didn't get many additional views after adding the program text, so I decided to post it again.

Comment: @trincot Thank you, I will do my best to stop being a "a three-star programmer" :) I believe that I tested all the previous versions of my program - I entered ascending and descending numberic sequences, and it worked exactly as I expected.

Comment: To begin with, I would recommend you change `void left_rotation(node **p)` to `void left_rotation(node *p)`.

Comment: What is the main issue that you faced?

Answer (score 0):

### What I learned while fixing this bug:

When working with an address like `node **p`, always remember:

- The address in the `p` variable can be accessed not only through `p`.
- Allowing its accidental change may cause severe distortion in the
  data structure.
- To protect the address in the `p` variable, you can pass it to a
  function as `node *const *p` or just as `node *p`.

In the end, I chose the latter option (passing the value to the function as `node *p`). Indeed, the `left_rotation` function doesn't have the task of altering the address stored in the `p` variable. Therefore, it's entirely possible to pass its value to the function as a local copy, and it won't affect anything.

The `left_rotation` function is specifically designed to alter connections in a data structure, and it will successfully achieve this goal by using the local address copy to access the data structure.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).